# Jquery Regex Password to accept only certain symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
^(?=.*\d+)[\-\/\\.,:;\?!\"'`_\(\)\[\] a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]{8,}$
```

Can you please let me know what the client side syntax would be for the above logic? It should only certain symbols in password like

```
-\/.,:;?!"'`_()[]
```

Comment: Allows the symbols you listed plus letters a to z capital and lower case and digits.  It also appears to support the foreign characters.

Comment: @BillyBigPotatoes: Yes correct, the same I want to place in Jquery syntax, can you please help me out on this

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery!!!

Comment: The syntax works in c#, where as I need the same to work in Jquery

Comment: `^(?=.*\d+)[\/.,:;?!"'`_()\[\] a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9-]{8,}$` should work for JavaScript. Use it like: `/^(?=.*\d+)[\/.,:;?!"'`_()\[\] a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9-]{8,}$/.test($('#myFormPasswordInput').val())`

Comment: @tenub: yes either javascript or jquery syntax, anything is fine

Comment: @tenub: can you please put the same thing in jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: almost seems easier to go the route of 'omission'.

Answer (score 0):

To create a regexpr in javascript you need to write it betwenn slashes.
As comments say, it's plain javascript, you don't need jQuery for that.

```
var regexpr = /^(?=.*\d+)[\-\/\\.,:;\?!\"'`_\(\)\[\] a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ0-9]{8,}$/;
if ( regexpr.test(password) ) {
  console.info('Valid password');
} else {
  console.info('Invalid password');
}
```

More informations about regular expression in javascript : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Last thing : are you sure about your regular expression ?

^(?=.*\d+) mean : can start with *anything*, need to be followed by at least one number.